# How to investigate open firewall ports further

Tags: ports, fuzzing

I scanned my friend's firewall (Zyxel SBG3500-N) with NMAP and I found some undocumented ports open with services:

> 8888 tcp open http  syn-ack lighttpd  1.4.34
>
> 18443 tcp open http syn-ack lighttpd  1.4.34

I could not find any info why those should be open and browser just returns *404 - Not Found* error. How could I investigate more those ports? Do you know any suitable fuzzing tool for this purpose?

Comment: Did you scan it from inside or outside the network?

Comment: Ask your friend if he set up port forwarding

Comment: It was scanned inside and no port forwarding.

Comment: I was able to do some fuzzing with OWASP ZAP and their basic files, but with no info.

Answer (score 1):

This is something used by routers: 'lighttpd'

A user can enable this in the router configuration page and add files to a designated folder or folders (likely the ones you were able to find). There they can store the files to run a simple webpage which can be accessed remotely just like any other website.

some info here: 
https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/http.lighttpd

Answer (score 0):

You could try SkipFish (https://code.google.com/archive/p/skipfish/)

It starts with a dictionary attack on the web server, and then combines that with a web-crawler.